# Office 365 - how to remove buttons at the right of the menu bar

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

In Office 365 (Word, Excel, etc.) there are a number of "action buttons" to the right of the menu bar (see example from my German Excel - "Kommentare" and "Freigeben").

How can I remove (hide) them? I have tried the regular way to change the menus but no luck so far.
[image: Excel 365 menu bar]

Comment: Looking at my installations here and how the Menu Bar works (unlike the Ribbon which can be customized), I do not think you can remove it. Sharing Office files is becoming a built in concept.

Comment: Since Office 365 is designed for online use, it makes sense that those buttons are there for sharing and commenting. A self-contained office suite such s LibreOffice would not have them.

Comment: Office 365 isn’t designed for online use. Those menu options appear in the perpetual versions Office 2019 and Office 2021.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to Microsoft to add an option for removing these buttons.
At the moment such an option doesn't exist, so there is no way to get rid
of these buttons.

The only thing you can do is add your vote to the feature request
[Please get rid of the new comment, editing/reviewing, and share buttons](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/13c16ba2-9da5-ed11-a81b-002248519701).